# Taylor expansion of the Error function

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

The error function $\operatorname{erf}(z)$ is defined by the integral 
$$
\operatorname{erf}(z)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^z e^{-t^2}\,dt,\quad t\in\mathbb R$$

> Find the Taylor expansion of $\operatorname{erf}(z)$ around $z_0=0$.

How to expand a function, when it is defined by the integral sign? Can somebody explain the steps to compute this?

Comment: start intuition with http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+erf%28x%29+at+the+origin

Comment: What's the Taylor expansion of $e^t$? Of $e^{-t^2}$? Of $\int e^{-t^2} dt$?

Comment: what wolframalpha uses is http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html

Answer (score 4):

As
$$e^t=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^n}{n!},$$
we have
$$e^{-t^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nt^{2n}}{n!}.$$
Integrating term to term (why is possible?),
$$\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\text{erf}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nt^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)n!}.$$

Answer (score 0):

For functions obeying just some very fairly modest restrictions, you differentiate under the integral sign by evaluating the function being integrated at the endpoint of the integral; this is the fundamental theorem of integral calculus.

So 
$$
\frac{d}{dz} \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^z e^{-t^2}dt =\frac{2}{\pi} e^{-z^2}
$$
At $z = 0$, this is $\frac{2}{\pi}$
And then the next derivative is easy:
$$
\left. \frac{d}{dz} \frac{2}{\pi} e^{-z^2} \right|_{z=0}= -\frac{2}{\pi} \left. 2ze^{-z^2} \right|_{z=0} = 0
$$
And then 
$$
\left. \frac{d^2}{dz^2} \frac{2}{\pi} e^{-z^2} \right|_{z=0} = \frac{2}{\pi} \left( \left. \left[ 4z^2-2\right]e^{-z^2} \right|_{z=0} \right) =\frac{4}{\pi}
$$
And so on from there.  Note that all the odd derivatives are zero.

Comment: I think there's a few numerical errors here? I may be wrong.